# Plotting a string of numbers from text file

Tags: python, file, matplotlib, plot, text-files

I have a text file `(m.txt)` with numbers in the form:

```
    4.52987812069
    3.71367858211
    4.50621674483
    5.17260331988
    5.06400394036
    etc
```

I want to plot these using `matplotlib` however when I do *all* of the numbers in `m.txt` get printed on 0 on the x-axis.  I obviously want each value in m to be printed along the x-axis starting at 0 and ending at `len(m) - 1`.

I know I'm messing up the for loop, but I can't get it to output correctly.  Thanks for your help.   Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open("m.txt") as m:
    for line in m:
        m_float = map(float,line.split())
        plt.plot(m_float,'bo')
        plt.ylabel('FLOC - % of line')
        plt.xlabel('Sample Number')
        plt.axis([-10,10,0,5])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open("m.txt") as m:
    for index, line in enumerate(m):
        m_float = map(float,line.strip())
        plt.plot(index, m_float,'bo')

    plt.ylabel('FLOC - % of line')
    plt.xlabel('Sample Number')
    plt.axis([-10,10,0,5])
    plt.show()
```

I replaced `split` with [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) for clarity. Notice, that I added [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get numbers with their indices. Later I pass them to `plt.plot`. I moved out of the loop `xlabel`, `ylabel` and `axis` calls, because there is no need to set labels and axis properties on each iteration, you can do it just once.

Comment: Thanks, got this to work.  However, it only works with .split() rather than .strip().  With .strip() it doesn't like the float argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass series of values to plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
with open("m.txt") as m:
    for line in m:
        m_float = float(line.split())
    x.append(m_float)

    plt.plot(x,'bo')
    plt.ylabel('FLOC - % of line')
    plt.xlabel('Sample Number')
    plt.axis([-10,10,0,6])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) you can do this without the loop, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m_float=np.loadtxt('m.txt')

plt.plot(m_float,'bo')
plt.ylabel('FLOC - % of line')
plt.xlabel('Sample Number')
plt.axis([-10,10,0,5])
plt.show()
```